# Signed in with my Apple ID on a friend’s device

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I lost my iPhone 8 and used my friend’s iPhone to find it. But I forgot to sign out from my friends iPhone.

Can I sign-off from all the devices that I have logged into with my Apple ID?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Simply visit [iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com) using a desktop browser and login with your Apple ID. Go to Settings. Under My Devices section, you should be able to see your friends iPhone. Click on the device and click on the blue button with cross to remove it from your account.

[image]

If you don’t see the Delete button, click Remove Device (below the device’s serial or IMEI number).

Refer to this help article for more details:

- https://help.apple.com/icloud/?lang=en-us#/mm25565a6496